# How can I get code completition/IntelliSense for library in Monaco editor?

Tags: vite, monaco-editor

I've built a library (written in TypeScript, built with Vite) that is intended to be a browser-based library. I've also built a companion "playground" application (think CodePen, TypeScript playground, etc) to experiment with the library. The editor portion of the playground is implemented using the [Monaco editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/). The editor renders fine and nicely provides basic IntelliSense and syntax highlighting, but I'd like for the editor to also show IntelliSense/code completion for the classes/functions inside of my library.

During the build process, Vite produces `.d.ts` files that look like the following:

```
declare class MyCoolClass {
    static func(x: number): number;
}

export { MyCoolClass };
```

From what I can gather, I can reference those `.d.ts` files and call the `addExtraLib` function in the Monaco library:

```
const typeDefinitions = `
declare class MyCoolClass {
    static func(x: number): number;
}

export { MyCoolClass };`;

monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(typeDefinitions, 'easing.d.ts');
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(typeDefinitions, 'easing.d.ts');

const editor = monaco.editor.create(aDomNode, {
    automaticLayout: true,
    value: '',
    language: 'typescript',
});
```

However, when typing into the editor, I don't see any code completion suggestions. **However**, if I remove `export { MyCoolClass };` from the type definitions, I see suggestions. I'm assuming this is because without an export, the declaration is treated as global, which is precisely what I want in this playground.

How can I use the generated `.d.ts` files to provide suggestions, without manually going through and stripping them of `export`s or post-processing them? I feel like maybe I'm missing something simple.